# BigQuery: API query gives ordered result without using order by

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my query (I use standard SQL):

```
(
SELECT
  x,
  ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT i IGNORE NULLS) AS sids
FROM (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    (SELECT
      x,
      y
    FROM
       table1)
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
       table5_*)
  ON
    y = e)
GROUP BY
  y,
  x)
```

If I execute this via API and download the result as a json through GCS bucket I get a file with the rows ordered by the ids in the aggregated array. Something like this:
{[x=>"xxxx", "ids"=>[]}
{[x=>"zzzz", "ids"=>[0]}
{[x=>"yyyy", "ids"=>[0,7]}
{[x=>"aaaa", "ids"=>[0,7,8]}
{[x=>"cccc", "ids"=>[0,8]}
{[x=>"ffff", "ids"=>[1,5]}
{[x=>"uuuu", "ids"=>[1,5,6,8,9]}
and so on...
When I execute the query through UI, I get no particular order, as I would expect.
Why do the rows appear ordered in this way in the exported result?

Comment: Unless you don't specify an order by explicitly, it will be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The ordering is arbitrary and could change at any time without an `ORDER BY`.